# Internet Explorer menu z-order: why isn't it right?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have what appears to be a z-order problem with Internet Explorer 9. It might be in other IE versions also, but not tested. I have to assume so.

This page: http://www.modelhelicopters.co.uk/partsfinder/trex500esp/frames

If you hover over the "All pages for this model" menu item on the parts finder menu bar (below the currency selector) - it should drop down a list of all the parts finder pages for the selected model helicopter.

If you view the same page in IE or Chrome etc, you will see how it should appear.

In IE9, the menu gets cut off at the top of the main exploded view image - suggesting the z-order is wrong.

I have tried amending this with a jquery snippet but it didn't fix IE9. I know the code was inserted by jquery as shown by firebug in firefox.

```
$j('div.std img[src*="/partsfinder/img"]').attr("style","position:relative;z-index:-100;");
```

I really do not know why this is not working.

Comment: Your site a bit of a mess with all that inline css. Have you considered moving it to a separate file??

Answer (score 0):

First your setting your z-index to a negative value?:

```
z-index:-100;
```

Put your z-index into the positive and if that doesn't work try !important:

```
z-index:999;

z-index:999 !important;
```

Comment: _and if that doesn't work try !important_ mmm not a great advice.

Comment: Please feel free to crawl through all that inline css and propose your own solution.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work? What inline CSS are you referring to please?